# Intercept calls to console.log in Chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, console

I have a script that I can't change that makes a lot of `console.log` calls. I want to add another layer and respond if the calls contain certain strings. This works in Firefox, but throws an "`Illegal invocation`" error in Chrome on the 4th line:

```
var oldConsole = {};
oldConsole.log = console.log;
console.log = function (arg) {
    oldConsole.log('MY CONSOLE!!');
    oldConsole.log(arg);
}
```

Any ideas how to get around that? I also tried cloning the console...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to call `console.log` in the context of `console` for chrome:

```
(function () {
  var log = console.log;
  console.log = function () {
    log.call(this, 'My Console!!!');
    log.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  };
}());
```

---

Modern language features can significantly simplify this snippet:

```
{
  const log = console.log.bind(console)
  console.log = (...args) => {
    log('My Console!!!')
    log(...args)
  }
}
```

Comment: nice... been looking for something like this.  Can this be used to decorate any function in javascript?

Comment: @Shane, this is the basic pattern for intercepting a function call, however I'd recommend against using it unless absolutely necessary. It's much better to just modify the function directly, or use OOP concepts.

Comment: building a framework where there's a lot of run time assembly of components, this would be a handy tool for an externally driven approach to debugging components or modifying existing components with plugins, etc.  Is there a performance hit for this approach?  Just curious what the drawbacks would be.  I won't be modifying intrinsic functions, only framework component methods.

Comment: every function you call is a "performance hit", but asynchronous JavaScript firing sporadically shouldn't bog down significantly.

Comment: looks like function chaining is significantly faster.  Just made a test.  http://jsperf.com/wrapped-function

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon, firefox seems to struggle with it a bit, but Chrome and Safari don't show much of a difference.

Comment: Just ran it in everything I've got, looks like it's good enough to use, thanks again man.  This makes life a lot easier for some of the weird little problems we are dealing with. :)

Comment: this doesnt accurately report line numbers

Comment: The `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` is redundant, unless [the browser doesn't support ECMAScript 5.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Browser_compatibility). You can just call `log.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, this answer is from 2012 and is almost 8 years old, so it can be significantly improved for modern browsers.

Comment: @zzzzBov I understand your answer is from 2012, but `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` would have been redundant for most browsers even then. I appreciate the update in response though.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's an old post but it can be useful anyway as others solution are not compatible with older browsers.

You can redefine the behavior of **each function** of the console (and for **all browsers**) like this:

```
// define a new console
var console = (function(oldCons){
    return {
        log: function(text){
            oldCons.log(text);
            // Your code
        },
        info: function (text) {
            oldCons.info(text);
            // Your code
        },
        warn: function (text) {
            oldCons.warn(text);
            // Your code
        },
        error: function (text) {
            oldCons.error(text);
            // Your code
        }
    };
}(window.console));

//Then redefine the old console
window.console = console;
```

Comment: cleanest answer i've seen yet for this type of question

Comment: [Window.console is read-only property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/console)
How can you override it?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the same logic, but call it off the console object so the context is the same.

```
if(window.console){
  console.yo = console.log;
  console.log = function(str){
    console.yo('MY CONSOLE!!');
    console.yo(str);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With ES6 new spread operator you can write it like this

```
(function () {
  var log = console.log;
  console.log = function () {
    log.call(this, 'My Console!!!', ...arguments);
  };
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be simply:

```js
console.log = (m) => terminal.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(m)
```

```css
#terminal {background: black; color:chartreuse}
```

```html
$ > <span id="terminal"></span>
<hr>        
<button onclick="console.log('Hello world!!')">3V3L</button>
<button onclick="console.log(document)">3V3L</button>
<button onclick="console.log(Math.PI)">3V3L</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To fully intercept the console, we can override every methods :

```
const bindConsole=function(onMessage){
    Object.keys(console)
    .filter(type=>typeof(console[type])==='function')// *1
    .forEach(type=>{
        let _old=console[type];
        console[type] = function (...args) {
            _old.apply(console,args);
            onMessage(type,args);// *2
        };
    });
};
```

For old browsers :

```
var bindOldConsole=function(onMessage){
    for(var k in console){// *1
        if(typeof(console[k])=='function')(function(type){
            var _old=console[type];
            console[type] = function () {
                _old.apply(console,arguments);
                onMessage(type,arguments);
            };
        })(k);
    }
};
```

---

- *1 Looks like **console** has only methods but better be sure.
- *2 You may block cyclic calls to console from **onMessage** by replacing this line with :

`if(!isCyclic())onMessage(type,args);`

```
// es6. Not sure concerning old browsers :(
const isCyclic=function (){
    let erst=(new Error()).stack.split('\n');
    return erst.includes(erst[1],2);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment (yet) on @ludovic-feltz answer, here is his answer corrected to allow string interpolation in the console :

```
// define a new console
var console = (function(oldCons){
    return {
        log: function(...text){
            oldCons.log(...text);
            // Your code
        },
        info: function (...text) {
            oldCons.info(...text);
            // Your code
        },
        warn: function (...text) {
            oldCons.warn(...text);
            // Your code
        },
        error: function (...text) {
            oldCons.error(...text);
            // Your code
        }
    };
}(window.console));

//Then redefine the old console
window.console = console;
```