# Checking if specific console error occurred/exists with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

I would like to check if a certain console error has occurred using javascript, and `alert()` myself if it has.

The error will look like this:

```
00:00:34:0359 TimeEvent.COMPLETE
    (anonymous function) @ VM17617:1
```

And the algorithm will look something like this:

```
function checkError(console) {
    if(console.error === "TimeEvent.COMPLETE") {
        alert("The error is present");
    }
}
```

I'm not very familiar with the console, and haven't gotten much further with Google research. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to try to hook into the actual event that triggers the error?

Comment: @Jan: That was my original plan but I can't figure that out either. This is the event: `try { __flash__toXML(console.error("00:02:30:0596 TimeEvent.COMPLETE")) ; } catch (e) { "<exception>" + e + "</exception>"; }` Any ideas?

Comment: That has to reside within a function or method somewhere. You could get the method, inject something into it and then overwrite it with your own logging.

Answer (score 4):

I ultimately solved my question by following [this blog post](http://tobyho.com/2012/07/27/taking-over-console-log/) on taking over the console with javascript.

Here is my final code:

```
var original = window.console
window.console = {
    error: function(){      

        //Gets text from error message.
        errorText = arguments['0'];

        if (errorText.includes('TimeEvent.COMPLETE')) {
            //DO STUFF HERE
        }

        original.error.apply(original, arguments)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the whole picture about how and when the console is getting the error.  If you raise the error yourself, or if you are able to catch it inside a `try catch`, that would be the best place to intercept those errors.

However, if you have no control about how those error are raised, you should try to intercept your console's error calls.  I never tried it myself but this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9216488/315493) explains how to intercept the console's `log` calls.  Knowing that the console usually have a function named `error` that is similar to the `log` function, I'm sure you could apply the same logic to intercept the errors sent to the console.

If you are using chrome, you may refer to the [console documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#errors-and-warnings) for more details about the error function.  I'm not sure if there's a standard but[Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh696634.aspx) and [Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/logging) also has support for console `error` function.