# How to get console.log output from eval()?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am using `eval()` to run a script from a string. Below is the code:

`eval('console.log("hello")');`

I will get `hello` from the console output. I wonder whether I can save the `hello` into an variable in the current context. So I am looking for something like this:

`const output = eval('console.log("hello")');` // I expect the console output is returned from `eval()` function.

But I get an `undefined` response. Is there a way for me to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercept calls to console.log in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216441/intercept-calls-to-console-log-in-chrome)

Comment: Well console does not return anything so why would you expect it to return something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is impossible because `console.log()` only returns undefined, however you can make a function that will return something.

Example:

```
console.oldLog = console.log;
console.log = function(value)
{
    console.oldLog(value);
    return value;
};

const output = eval('console.log("hello")');
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: That's getting into a bit of dangerous territory, messing with predefined stuff.

Comment: Good answer though. :)

Comment: Brilliant solution!Even though it messes with predefined functions,its very useful!

Comment: I had the same use case and I created a public package based on this approach - https://www.npmjs.com/package/capture-console-logs

Answer (score 1):

While the first answer works, it causes a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error for my case.
Think this might be a better solution.

```
const originalLog = console.log;

console.log = function (...value) {
  originalLog.apply(console, value);
  return value;
};

const response = eval(code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
out = ''
console.log = function(val){out = out + ' ' + val}
eval('console.log("test string")')
```