# Run JavaScript code independent inside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in JavaScript in browsers, to run an other script stored as string independently from the main JavaScript and also get the console output from that script in a way that it is not (just) printed to the console?

Basically I want something like this:

```
var script = 'console.log("Hello World");'

var consoleOut = script.runAsJS();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I load a javascript file dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute JavaScript code stored as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string)

Comment: @JayVaghasiya it doesn't get the console outputs

Comment: @Karan It was already posted as answer and it isn't independent and also doesn't give the console

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417440/how-to-get-console-log-output-from-eval

Comment: @LeaftheLegend Yes thats an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could look into [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Hopefully this is what you mean by 'independent from the main javascript'. If you mean as in variables from the outer scope will not be defined in the string, eval() will not work for you. It is treated as part of the same program.

Edit: also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781285/specify-scope-for-eval-in-javascript) on specifying the scope of eval()

If you want to store the console.log in a variable, try something like this:

```
var script = 'console.log("Hello World");'
var consoleOut = [];
script = script.replace(/console\.log/g,"consoleOut.push");
eval(script);
```

Edit: as suggested by comments, eval is often not the best in terms of security. A more efficient and secure option may be [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), however the docs mention that `Function` still suffers from security issues:

```
var script = 'console.log("Hello World");'
var consoleOut = [];
scriptFunction = new Function(script.replace(/console\.log/g,"consoleOut.push"));
scriptFunction();
```

Comment: in what way _is_ `eval` independent?

Comment: Well I want that kind of independence and also I want to separately get the console outputs

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now

Comment: Since your script is stored as a string, what if you were to `.replace` all `console.log`s with a custom function that returns the value you want?

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help

Comment: @user11914177 The use of `eval()` is not advised for most use cases. Often there is a better solution. If you can explain in more detail what you want to achieve we can help you with a better solution. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

Comment: Yes, eval can definitely be dangerous

Comment: Depends on the use case

Comment: @MarkBaijens thanks for that warning, this site references the `Function` is this now safe to use or is it still possible to exploit it?

Comment: @user11914177 It's definitely safer to use the function wrapper, I'm not an expert on this area but I think it's still dangerous because it still uses code injection. Therefore if you are not 100% in control of the code that is inserted then you still have security issues. It's a bit like SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

What environment?

In browser, you can use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

In Node/Deno you can use [VM](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_executing_javascript) or [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) separate process.

Comment: Thanks,   I added this to response

Comment: And I added the answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

*To run an other script stored as string* you can use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) as [suggested by answer from @Leaf the Legend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62772596/9695286). And for script to run *independently from the main JavaScript* you can use [`IIFE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

So combining `eval` and `IIFE` you may get your desired result. Like `(function() { eval(script) })();`

Below is small snippet which may elaborate better.

```js
// variable from global scope.
let a = 10;

function runAsJS(script) {
  (function() {
    eval(script)
  })();
}

let script = `
  let a = 10; 
  a += 10;
  console.log('a from eval script', a);`;

runAsJS(script);
console.log('a from global scope', a);
```

Comment: Well that just is Leaf the Legends answer

Comment: No, for `eval` yes, but I have suggest to use `IIFE` which can make difference and variable defined inside `script` will have limited scope to itself only. It will not affect global variables.