# How can I debug my Cordova app on Oculus Quest?

Tags: cordova, three.js, oculus, quest

I can debug my Cordova app on an Android Samsung phone using Chrome -> 'chrome://inspect/#devices'

This page also shows my Oculus Quest and the Cordova app running in it.

But pressing 'Inspect' gets me a 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'

How can I debug my Cordova app on Oculus Quest?

The problem I am having is that the app I am running uses three.js code, which runs fine on Samsung, but seems to fail on Quest. Debugging might help to find the problem.

Comment: It might be necessary to enable USB debugging via the Oculus app, see https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/oculus-browser/browser-remote-debugging/?locale=de_DE

Comment: Thanks, to install apk on Quest I already had to enable USB debugging so it's not about that. In meanwhile I thought I could try to capture console as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216441/intercept-calls-to-console-log-in-chrome ... trying that next.

Comment: Did you get your Cordova and Three.js app running on a Quest?